# How i could replicate redis data (master - slave configuration) in aws elastic cache redis asynchronously.

Tags: redis

Can anyone suggest me a way to intercept communication between master and slave redis and use that buffered data to write in AWS elastic cache

Answer (score 0):

Redis replication protocol is open. You can write your own 'server' that would appear just like another slave to master, but will push date to elastic cache.

By the way, isn't ElasticCache support Redis directly?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is anything already implemented like this in java